# Create a new column with it named variable using mutale

Tags: r, dplyr

Minimal example: A small dataframe and a variable that holds the name of a new column I want to create.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:5],
                  Q1  = sample(0:10, 5, replace=T),
                  Q2  = sample(0:10, 5, replace=T)
)
```

I also have a new column name stored in a variable

```
MY_NEW_COL <- "My_Col_Sum"
```

I want to add a new column named My_Col_Sum that is the sum of Q1 and Q2 using mutate. I have tried

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(get(MY_NEW_COL) = Q1 + Q2)
```

and

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(!!MY_NEW_COL = Q1 + Q2)
```

But in both cases I get an error message:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"df1 %>%
    mutate(get(MY_NEW_COL) ="
```

What is the correct syntax for what should be a very common operation. Clearly, I could have done this by writing

df1 %>%
mutate(My_Col_Sum = Q1 + Q2)

but I do want to define the name of the column in a global variable that is very visible, and the real problem will assign a much more complex formula to `My_Col_Sum`.

Many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for that is `!!MY_NEW_COL :=`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate(!!MY_NEW_COL := Q1 + Q2)

#  ID Q1 Q2 My_Col_Sum
#1  A  9  2         11
#2  B  0 10         10
#3  C  1  9         10
#4  D 10 10         20
#5  E  4  2          6
```

Comment: Thank you. By trial and error I also found that {{MY_NEW_COL} := Q1 + Q2 worked, but it appears to be old, and I'm not sure it's used any longer. Is the !! syntax the accepted way going forward?

Comment: I think both `{{}}:=` and `!!` should be okay to use.